# Parse-Server push notifications with

Tags: android, json, parse-platform, parse-server

I have been trying to update an old app that used parse.com. I have setup my own instance of parse server and directed the app to use the new instance. Everything works now in the app with the exception of the push notifications. I created a new firebase application and enabled FCM. I have placed the keys in myConfig.json which i reference when i start parse from the terminal. It looks like:

```
{
    "appId": "idofapp",
    "masterKey": "master,
    "cloud": "/home/ubuntu/cloud/",
    "databaseURI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/test-app",
    "push": {
        "android":{
            "senderId": "99999999999",
            "apiKey": "BigLongKeyGeneratedFromFirebase"
            }
    }
}
```

I have created a cloud/main.js which i reference in the config file. It looks like:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("SendPush", function(request) {
     var msg = request.params.message;
     var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
     var user = request.params.user;
     query.equalTo("objectId", user);
     Parse.Push.send({
     where: query,
     data:{
          alert: {
               "title" : msg,
               "body" : msg
          },
          sound: 'default'
     }
     }, {
     useMasterKey: true,
     success: function(){
          response.success("Push Sent!");
     },
     error: function(error){
          response.error("Error while trying to send push " + error.message);
     }
     });
});
```

I enabled verbose logging since it wasn't giving me any information about why the push notifications were not being delivered. It prints out the following five times only changing the Status-Id.

```
    verbose: REQUEST for [POST] /parse/functions/SendPush: {
  "message": "You have a new message ",
  "user": "bXYVlwltiN"
} method=POST, url=/parse/functions/SendPush, x-parse-session-token=r:6d11549cc2f2e7ffd64ba07a6d327e8d, x-parse-application-id=app, x-parse-client-version=a1.15.8, x-parse-app-build-version=1, x-parse-app-display-version=1.0, x-parse-os-version=8.0.0, user-agent=Parse Android SDK 1.15.8 (com.company.name/1) API Level 26, x-parse-installation-id=44123cf9-65fa-4871-8798-22eafa291711, content-type=application/json, content-length=57, host=ec2-19-198-39-191.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:1337, connection=Keep-Alive, accept-encoding=gzip, message=You have a new message , user=bXYVlwltiN
verbose: REQUEST for [POST] /parse/push: {
  "where": {
    "objectId": "bXYVlwltiN"
  },
  "data": {
    "alert": {
      "title": "You have a new message ",
      "body": "You have a new message "
    },
    "sound": "default"
  }
} method=POST, url=/parse/push, user-agent=node-XMLHttpRequest, Parse/js1.11.1 (NodeJS 7.10.1), accept=*/*, content-type=text/plain, host=localhost:1337, content-length=269, connection=close, objectId=bXYVlwltiN, title=You have a new message , body=You have a new message , sound=default
verbose: RESPONSE from [POST] /parse/push: {
  "headers": {
    "X-Parse-Push-Status-Id": "ZOrTd4OylW"
  },
  "response": {
    "result": true
  }
} X-Parse-Push-Status-Id=ZOrTd4OylW, result=true
```

No notifications are delivered. Can you please tell me what I have missed?

I have changed the cloud function to the following and still get the same error:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("SendPush", function(request, response) {

var userId = request.params.user;
    var message = "sening a test message"; //request.params.message;
    var queryUser = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    queryUser.equalTo('objectId', userId);
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    query.matchesQuery('user', queryUser);

    Parse.Push.send({
      where: query,
      data: {
        alert: message,
        badge: 0,
        sound: 'default'
      }
    }, {
      success: function() {
        console.log('##### PUSH OK');
        response.success();
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log('##### PUSH ERROR');
        response.error('ERROR');
      },
      useMasterKey: true
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, response is undefined. It shows ils be the second argument of your sendPush cloud functions

Comment: I have changed the cloud function to the function referenced above and still get the same message.

Comment: What do you mean you still get the same message?

Also you should probably try the promise based API. it's more robust and reliable.


    Parse.Push.send({ where, data }, { useMasterKey: true })).then(() => {
       response.success();
    }).catch(() => {
       response.error('ERRROR');
    });

Comment: I just switched the code to use firebase for everything eliminating parse server. It took less time to do that then it was taking me to figure out why the push wouldn't work thru parse...